# want to display the text based on click on the checkbox in vf page

Tags: salesforce

want to display text in filed based onclick of checkbox in VF page.but the same checkbox is calling one method.
code is bellow....please write controller. need urget help..

```
<apex:outputPanel id="jobPanel">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

Apex Class:

```
public class Test 
{
   public Boolean isChecked { get; set; }       
   public String myText{get;set;}
   public void controllerMethod()
   {
       myText = 'Your Text field rendered';
       //assign text field values
   }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="Test" >
  <apex:form >  
   <apex:pageBlock id="jobBlock">
      <apex:inputCheckbox id="inche" value="{!isChecked}" >
          <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!controllerMethod}" rerender="jobPanel" />
      </apex:inputCheckbox>

      <apex:outputPanel id="jobPanel">
          <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!isChecked}">
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                   <apex:inputText value="{!myText}"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>                           
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:outputPanel>
   </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Hope it helps you